# Javascript - Canvas, How To make ball travel in zig zag

Tags: javascript, modernizr

Hey Guys I am having a problem with some JavaScript on a Canvas. Basically, I cant figure out how to make the ball travel in a zig zag. I am new to JavaScript and still learning it so if any of you guys could help me it would be greatly appreciated. So my question is how would I go about making the ball travel in a zig zag? Currently it just does a straight line from left to right.

Here is my Code

```
// JavaScript Document
window.addEventListener('load', eventWindowLoaded, false); 

function eventWindowLoaded() {
    canvasApp(); 
}

function canvasSupport () { 
    return Modernizr.canvas;
}

function canvasApp() {

    // test if Modernizr has been loaded
    if (!canvasSupport()) { 
        return; 
    }

    var pointImage = new Image(); 
    // put an image into an image object
    pointImage.src = "point.png"; 

    function drawScreen () {

        // fill the background
        context.fillStyle = '#EEEEEE';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, theCanvas.width, theCanvas.height);
        // Draw  a Box around the fill
        context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
        context.strokeRect(1, 1, theCanvas.width - 2, theCanvas.height-2);

        // Create ball

        if (moves > 0 ) { 
            moves--; 
            ball.x += xunits; 
            ball.y += yunits;
        }

        // Draw points to illustrate path

        points.push({
            x: ball.x,
            y:ball.y
        });

        // for loop with drawImage inside the loop to draw the points

        for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) { 
            context.drawImage(pointImage, points[i].x, points[i].y, 1, 1);
        }
        context.fillStyle = "#000000"; 
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball_radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
    }

    var speed = 10;
    // coordinates of the left hand point
    var p1 = {
        x: 20,
        y: 250
    }; 
    var p2 = {
        x: 480,
        y: 250
    };
    // distance between left and right x coordinates
    var dx = p1.x - p2.x; 
    var dy = p1.y - p2.y;
    // Calculate the distance between points
    var distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    var moves = distance / speed;
    var xunits = (p2.x - p1.x) / moves;
    var yunits = (p2.y - p1.y) / moves;
    var ball = {
        x: p1.x, 
        y: p1.y
    };
    var points = new Array();
    var the_interval = 20
    var ball_radius = 5

    // save the context in a variable
    theCanvas = document.getElementById("canvasOne"); 
    context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");

    // call the drawscreen function every 33 miliseconds
    setInterval(drawScreen, the_interval); 

}
```

I am using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Without writing to crazy of a math function, perhaps it would a good idea to use a sine wave as the "zig zag." Check out http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sin.asp or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sin

Comment: Ok thanks but I don't understand how to use this where do I put this method? I can't tell if its me just being oblivious or the fact that I've been staring at this exact same code for 6 hours racking my brain and just can't seem to see it.

Answer (score 0):

[Calculate velocity and direction of a ball to ball collision based on mass and bouncing coefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424459/calculate-velocity-and-direction-of-a-ball-to-ball-collision-based-on-mass-and-b)

```
     -Your answer can be found in there. The problem with your original code was that you calculated the total change in distance over the total time. If the zig zag is going to move left to right at a 45 degree angle then the absolute value of the speed of |y| == x. create a listener or loop to switch the value of y from positive to negative values depending when you want to zig or zag. check out that older post it should clear things up
```

Comment: You are correct it goes directly in a straight line from left to right, It doesn't even matter which direction it goes as long as it does it like this [Example Zig Zag](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/cookbook/ch1/1369_01_05/)
Thank you for offering to help me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like some homework :-) Anyway here you got solution with using Sin. It's definitely not bad idea to create zig-zag with it as you did not defined closer what exact shape do you need.

```
(function () {
  var startPoint = { x: 0, y: 250 },
      endPoint = { x: 500, y: 250 },
      ball = { x: startPoint.x, y: startPoint.y },
      canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
      context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
      return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
              window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
              window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
              window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
              window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
              function( callback ){
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
              };
    })();

  function draw() {

    var dx = endPoint.x - startPoint.x, 
        dy = endPoint.y - startPoint.y,
        a = (function () { if (dy !== 0) { return dx/dy; } else { return 0; }})(),
        b = startPoint.y - a*startPoint.x,
        y = function (x) { return a*x + b; };

    ball.x = ball.x + 1;
    ball.y = y(ball.x) + Math.sin(ball.x*0.1)*10;

    context.fillStyle = '#EEEEEE';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    context.strokeRect(1, 1, canvas.width-2, canvas.height-2);

    context.fillStyle = "#000000"; 
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(ball.x, ball.y, 5, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();

    window.requestAnimFrame(draw);
  }

  window.requestAnimFrame(draw);

})();
```

It only zig-zags on Y, but you can use this idea and add or change your own "deviations" in both X and Y. You can also add Modernizr to detect canvas but I think in this question it's irrevelant. Hope it helps ;-) You can try it here --> http://jsbin.com/ahefoq/1 <--. Enjoy!

mz